# Web Interface for training by dragging and dropping pieces

Tags: software, training, websites, chessboards

Is there any web chess interface that lets me handle chess pieces as I like?

- I mean it will allow me to drag and drop pieces wherever I want them to be on the chessboard and add as many pieces as I like on it.
- I don't want an engine.
- I need simply an interface on the web, or some simple html files that I can use on my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php.

It has (among other nice features) two boards: on the left one, you can do everything you like, and the right one allows only legal moves. After you are done with the analysis, you can easily get the pgn code. Pretty simple and useful site. It is free and no registration is required. Enjoy!

Comment: This link does not provide a drag and drop interface, but a click-click one instead. However, it is combined with a drag-and-drop interface for playing against an engine with the option to turn off the engine, which makes for a drag and drop chessboard for making legal moves only. (http://www.apronus.com/chess/computer.htm)

Answer (score 6):

There's also the [lichess board editor](http://en.lichess.org/editor). It supports all the features you want, and will also let you get a computer analysis or play the position against the engine.

Answer (score 3):

The chess.com analysis board is probably what you are after, you don't even need to have legal moves.

http://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor

Comment: Ok I will try it :) But is it free ?

Comment: Can you follow the link and use it?